# Bluetooth often requires cycling power supply to be recognized

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, bluetooth

Upon booting my PC or waking it from sleep I often find Bluetooth to be unavailable despite Wifi continuing to work flawlessly.
Rebooting my PC does nothing to resolve the issue. If however, I turn off the power supply and wait briefly before rebooting my PC the fans start to spin-up, stop, then spin-up fully and my PC boots with the Bluetooth functional. I would guess this has something to do with draining an on-board battery on the motherboard.

- When the Bluetooth is non-functional a normal reboot into either Windows 10 or Ubuntu fails to restore functionality.
- Win10 device manager shows “Currently, this hardware device is not connected to the computer” when Bluetooth is non-functional.

I have a [Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I v4.2 Wifi and Bluetooth card](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GC-WB867D-I-rev-42). My motherboard is a [Gigabyte X58A-UD3R](http://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X58A-UD3R-rev-20). The wireless card is attached via a PCIE express port as well as a USB 3.0 header for Bluetooth functionality.

Any diagnostic tips would be appreciated.

---

## Less Important Details

- <sub>Naturally I have reinstalled the win10 drivers multiple times, but as the problem transcends operating systems I don't feel that's relevant. The relevant drivers come packaged with Ubuntu.</sub>
- <sub>I have tried multiple headers on the motherboard</sub>

Comment: These drivers you have installed.  They specifically indicate Windows 10 support?  If they don't then the drivers are not compatible with Windows 10.  Windows 10 brought significant changes to the Bluetooth stack.

Comment: @Ramhound They're listed on the page for the card, Win10 is indeed listed. It's a modern card.